# How to reproject all the vector files in a folder to a particular projection using ogr2ogr?

Tags: qgis, vector, ogr2ogr

We have a folder with all sorts of vector files like tab,shp,dxf. Many of the files are in different projection. I would like to convert all the files to EPSG: 4326 and eventually  the non-shapefiles to shapefiles.

I've used the following command

For  %%f in ("*.shp",".*tab","*.dxf") do ogr2ogr -t_SRS EPSG:4326 "ESRI Shapefile" "%~dpnf.shp" "%%f"

It say's.."Failure COuldn't fetch requested layer".

And how to save the output files in a separate folder, not in the same folder itself

Edit:

I've attached the image of the error

[image]

Comment: Why don't you split the script in 3? One for shp, one for tab and one for dxf? I'm not sure that you can convert them all in a new EPSG, if all of them don't have an associated projection system (like dxf I suppose). You have to set the original EPSG for all of them.

Comment: I would guess that first failure happens here because the -f switch for the format is missing: `ogr2ogr -t_SRS EPSG:4326 "ESRI Shapefile"`

Comment: I've tried the command with -f & also the batch as suggested by xunilk in the comment section. It gives the same error. I've edited the question & attached an image of it

Answer (score 4):

For doing that is required a script; not a command. As I don't know which operative system you have, I am going to use a bash script in my Linux system (in Windows the equivalent is a bat file) and by using only shapefiles.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.shp
do
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 out_data/$i $i
done
```

The above script (named as **convert** and running with **./convert**) worked well and it projected all the shapefiles in the current directory to ESPG:4326 and it saved them with the same name in the **out_data** directory (**out_data** must be created in the directory where is running the script).

The following image is the working directory with diferents shapefiles and raster (included the script and **out_data**):

[image]

Directory **out_data** after running the script (the shapefiles were loaded to QGIS with the fly projection activated for verification purpose). It only contain shapefiles with the desired projection.

[image]

**Editing Note**:

I didn't know the bat sintaxis but I found it. It's precisely in one line command. The correct sintaxis is:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.shp) DO ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 "out_data/%%i" "%%i%"
```

The above bat file (named as **convert.bat** and running with **convert**) worked well and it projected all the shapefiles in the current directory to ESPG:4326 and it saved them with the same name in the **out_data** directory (**out_data** must be created in the directory where is running the bat file).

Successful execution of the bat file in my XP Windows System:

[image]

Comment: I've edited the question and attached an image. COuld you have a look ? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Did you use my bat file exactly? I saw that you are employing spaces in shapefiles' names. This is not a very good practice. Please, create a new folder and put in it my bat file and three shapefiles (*.dbf, *.prj, *.shp, *.shx) without spaces in their names. Don't forget to create the **out_data** directory. Run my bat file.

Comment: OK. The problem was with the spaces in the names. But we can't do much about it. Those files are from the client. The folder will have tab files, dxf files, shp files & all sorts of vector files. 

Another question. Instead of creating a folder manually, how to create it during run time ? 

Anyway, Thanks for the quick response