# How add a text field and then reproject all shapefiles which are in sub folders

Tags: python, arcpy, coordinate-system, ogr, fields-attributes

I have a folder and inside of that folder, I have about 500 sub folders which contain on average about 5 shapefiles each.

What I want to do is:

- to check if there is a field, lets say `field_1`, and if it is not in  the attribute table, to add it (`TEXT length = 6`) and then
- to reproject all the shapefiles preferably with `ogr2org` to EPSG:3035

I find this [question 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138720/how-to-reproject-all-the-vector-files-in-a-folder-to-a-particular-projection-usi) but my data are in multiple directories and this [question 2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/ogr2ogr-convert-all-shapefiles-in-a-directory) which is for converting all shapefiles in a directory.

the above questions give me food for thought of how can someone do something that I am looking for.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include a code snippet to show what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the arcpy/python script flow:

1. Use os.walk to iterate through directory and sub-directories
2. Once shp is found use [ListFields](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//018v00000012000000) function to get a list of all shp field names
3. Use condition if logic to check if field name exists in fc from ListFields list
4. If field name does not exist use [Add Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000) method to create the field
5. Use [Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) method to re-project shp

Comment: If using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 or later I would recommend using arcpy.da.Walk over os.walk.